# How can a loop through sublist at JSON array

Tags: sql, json

I need to get all items from a sublist in a JSON array in SQL

JSON:

```
[{"IDPERSON": "0000001",
  "IDCONTTACT": "101010",
  "PHONES": [{"PHONE": "0000000",
              "TYPE": "4"}]},
 {"IDPERSON": "0000002",
  "IDCONTTACT": "202020",
  "PHONES": [{"PHONE": "1111111",
              "TYPE": "0"},
             {"PHONE": "2222222",
              "TYPE": "5"},
             {"PHONE": "3333333",
              "TYPE": "4"}]}]
```

Result:

```
IDPERSON IDCONTTACT    PHONE  TYPE
0000001      101010  0000000     4
0000002      202020  1111111     0
0000002      202020  2222222     5
0000002      202020  3333333     4
```

Comment: Hi - many more details are needed. What database are you using? MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, etc all have differing JSON APIs. Is the JSON stored in a blob/clob column?

Comment: Please, tag your DBMS. JSON is not a basic entity in SQL world, so every database has individual way to work with it.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, you will want to use a CTE to accomplish this task. The answer below uses MySQL, however, the logic is transferable:

```
with recursive cte(ind1, ind2, pid, cont, ph, t, val) as (
   select 1, 0, json_extract(val, '$[0].IDPERSON'), json_extract(val, '$[0].IDCONTTACT'), json_extract(val, '$[0].PHONES[0].PHONE'), json_extract(val, '$[0].PHONES[0].TYPE'), val from js
   union all
   select (case when ind2 + 1 < json_length(val, concat('$[', ind1, '].PHONES')) then ind1 else ind1 + 1 end),
          (case when ind2 + 1 < json_length(val, concat('$[', ind1, '].PHONES')) then ind2 + 1 else 0 end),
          json_extract(val, concat('$[', ind1 ,'].IDPERSON')), json_extract(val, concat('$[', ind1, '].IDCONTTACT')), json_extract(val, concat('$[', ind1, '].PHONES[', ind2, '].PHONE')), json_extract(val, concat('$[', ind1, '].PHONES[', ind2, '].TYPE')), val
   from cte 
   where ind1 < json_length(val) or ind2 < json_length(val, concat("$[", ind1, "].PHONES"))
)
select pid IDPERSON, cont IDCONTTACT, ph PHONE, t TYPE from cte;
```

Output:

| IDPERSON | IDCONTTACT | PHONE | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0000001 | 101010 | 0000000 | 4 |
| 0000002 | 202020 | 1111111 | 0 |
| 0000002 | 202020 | 2222222 | 5 |
| 0000002 | 202020 | 3333333 | 4 |

See the [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eab53d9743244924dc052d6108072953).